# Cómo grafica la librería matplotlib cuando hay datos faltantes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, timeseries

supongamos que tenemos una gráfica donde se ven los consumos de energía en un día de "n" cantidad de medidores. Cada punto esta separado uno de otro por un lapso de 15 minutos.
Si faltan datos en el contenedor, donde tengo los datos de la energía consumida de cada uno de los medidores, como se ven graficados los datos?

- Opción 1: Se produce un corté en la línea graficada?
- Opción 2: Conecta con una línea recta entre punto antes del corte y el punto
  después del mismo?
- Opción 3: Conecta la recta con valor 0?

Realizo un modesto dibujo para que se entienda mejor mi duda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que se puede dar de alguna otra forma, y que esto podría variar acorde a cómo tenga definido el DataSet, pero cualquier información con más precisión al respecto es agradecida.

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras decir con "datos faltantes". Supongamos que se toma una muestra cada segundo, y que el eje X va etiquetado por el instante de las muestras. Y que en ciertas muestras el dato es NaN (pero la muestra existe). En ese caso tendrías la primera gráfica. Si en ciertas muestras el dato es 0 obviamente tendrías la tercera. También si haces un  `fillna()` (que reemplaza los NaN con ceros) en el primer caso. Si hay un "salto" en el propio índice, por ejemplo tras el instante 100 se pasa al 150, y los 50 intermedios no están, tendrías la gráfica del medio.

Comment: Si quieres evitar la gráfica del medio puedes hacer un "resample" de los datos usando pandas. De este modo Pandas crea un índice "continuo" en el que no faltan datos, agregando los que haya en el periodo, o poniendo NaN si no hay ninguno en el periodo. Así podrías obtener la primera gráfica (o la última si haces .fillna())

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Era exactamente lo que necesitaba.
Creo que no puedo marcarla como respuesta a la pregunta, debido a que es un comentario, y no una respuesta como tal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acorde al aporte del usuario abulafia quien respondió al post en forma de comentario, manifiesto su criterio en formato de respuesta para cerrar el tema.

Depende de lo que quieras decir con "datos faltantes". Supongamos que se toma una muestra cada segundo, y que el eje X va etiquetado por el instante de las muestras. Y que en ciertas muestras el dato es NaN (pero la muestra existe). En ese caso tendrías la primera gráfica. Si en ciertas muestras el dato es 0 obviamente tendrías la tercera. También si haces un fillna() (que reemplaza los NaN con ceros) en el primer caso. Si hay un "salto" en el propio índice, por ejemplo tras el instante 100 se pasa al 150, y los 50 intermedios no están, tendrías la gráfica del medio.

Si quieres evitar la gráfica del medio puedes hacer un "resample" de los datos usando pandas. De este modo Pandas crea un índice "continuo" en el que no faltan datos, agregando los que haya en el periodo, o poniendo NaN si no hay ninguno en el periodo. Así podrías obtener la primera gráfica (o la última si haces .fillna())